# Is there a way to get notified when a property changes groups in a sorted collection?

Tags: c#, sorting, collections, notifications, grouping

To be more specific, let's say we have a collection sorted by properties P1 and P2 like this:

- A 1
- A 2
- A 2
- A 3
- B 1
- B 1
- B 2
- B 3

When doing a foreach through the collection, I want to get notified whenever a property changes.
So for P1 I need the following 4 notifications in this particular order:

1. OnBeforeGroup(P1, "A")
2. OnAfterGroup(P1, "A")
3. OnBeforeGroup(P1, "B")
4. OnAfterGroup(P1, "B")

For P2 this would make 12 notifications, spare me the list.

Of course, I can do this in every use case by saving the "old" property values within the foreach loop (OldP1 = P1) and firing an event/executing a method when P1 != OldP1, but that's not reusable.

Is there a collection that already implements this pattern?
If not, any advice how to make it more reusable?

Edit: Note, I just want to get notified during foreach loop if some property value is different than it was in previous iteration, this has nothing to do with INotifyPropertyChanged etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET has [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) but that's used to watch changes happening to objects stored and collection itself. Your collection isn't changing (given I understood you correctly) - you just want to get notified during loop if some property value is different than it was in previous iteration.

Something that might point you in the right direction, in terms of having reusable code:

```
public class PropertyWatcher<TSource>
{
    // initialization code omitted
    private Dictionary<string, object> previousValues;
    private Dictionary<string, Func<TSource, object>> selectors; 

    public void RegisterWatcher<TSource>(Func<TSource, object> propertySelector, 
        string propertyName)
    {
        this.selectors.Add(propertyName, propertySelector);
        this.previousValues.Add(propertyName, null);
    }

    public void NotifyIfDifferent<TObject, TPropertyType>(TSource currentItem)
    {
        foreach (var key in this.selectors.Keys)
        {
            var selector = this.selectors[key];
            var currentValue = selector(currentItem);
            if (!currentValue.Equals(this.previousValues[key]))
            {
                // raise notification, event; antyhing to your liking
            }

            this.previousValues[key] = currentValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And, assuming we're dealing with `P1` and `P2` properties you mentioned, usage would look like this:

```
var list = new List<SomeObject>(); // list of items you intend to watch
var watcher = new PropertyWatcher<SomeObject>();
watcher.RegisterWatcher((SomeObject o) => o.P1, "P1");
watcher.RegisterWatcher((SomeObject o) => o.P2, "P2");
foreach (var item in list)
{
    watcher.NotifyIfDifferent(item);
}
```

This is by no means complete solution. It should work when simple values are concerned (so `.Equals` can handle comparing easily). Of course, you still need to add some event to `PropertyWatcher` class and perhaps tweak it here and there - but I think general idea is fairly easy to grasp.

For more advanced scenarios though, I suppose you'll have to work o more generic approach.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if C# has aspects, but that could be one place to look.  Otherwise, you could add a change delegate to your class and then in the set part of your property methods, you could call the delegate:

```
private delegate void beforeGroup( MyObject current, MyObject changesTo );
private delegate void afterGroup( MyObject current, MyObject changedFrom );

public MyObject P1 {
    get {
        return p1;
    }
    set {
        beforeGroup( p1, value );
        MyObject oldValue = p1;
        p1 = value;
        afterGroup( p1, oldValue );
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't appropriate in my use case.